# How to handle JSON with null values using Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I have decoded my JSON Api, so I can display it in my contentView, but I got this error

> valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
> [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1),
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "DEALER_PICTURE", intValue: nil)],
> debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.",
> underlyingError: nil))

and I realized, I have a null values in my JSON

```
  "id":8,
  "DEALER_NAME":"Bluejam",
  "DEALER_ADDRESS":"85703 Westridge Trail",
  "DEALER_PICTURE":null
```

How to fix this error, without changing the JSON value?
Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var locations: [ServiceLocationJSON] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if locations.isEmpty{
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    ProgressView()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }else{
                VStack{
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(0..<locations.count){ index in
                            VStack(spacing: 10){
                                Text(locations[index].DEALER_PICTURE)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear{
            getLocationData(url: "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/null_value.json?key=e57d0e40"){
                (locations) in
                self.locations = locations
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ServiceLocationJSON: Identifiable, Decodable{
    var id: Int
    var DEALER_NAME: String
    var DEALER_PICTURE: String
}

func getLocationData(url: String, completion: @escaping ([ServiceLocationJSON])->()){
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!){ (data, _, err) in
        if err != nil{
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        do{
            let locations = try
                JSONDecoder().decode([ServiceLocationJSON].self, from: data!)
            completion(locations)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it optional

```
var DEALER_PICTURE: String?
```

Comment: Now I got this error `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file Test10/ContentView.swift, line 25
2021-03-30 16:36:43.126236+0700 Test10[4930:349342] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file Test10/ContentView.swift, line 25
(lldb) `

Comment: Change `Text(locations[index].DEALER_PICTURE)` to  `Text(locations[index].DEALER_PICTURE ?? "Empty")`